# Error: The template parameters are invalid. Google Cloud function to run an existing dataflow template GCS_Text_Bigquery

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm building a Cloud function, with storage trigger and trying to run a dataflow from within. I created a dataflow job "jsonbq-1", with an existing `GCS_Text_BigQuery` template, have created a simple uDF to take the incoming CSV Data and put into tables. 
The Cloud function is executed and the Dataflow is called but there is no response, and the error displayed in the `log:Error`:  The template parameters are invalid.

I'm not sure where the error is.

**`Index.js` looks like this.**

```
`const google = require('googleapis'); 
 //const { auth } = require('google-auth-library');

 exports.goWithTheDataFlow  = (event, callback) => {

 const file = event.data;
 const context = event.context;

 console.log(`Event ${context.eventId}`);
 console.log(`  Event Type: ${context.eventType}`);
 console.log(`  Bucket: ${file.bucket}`);
 console.log(`  File: ${file.name}`);
 console.log(`  Metageneration: ${file.metageneration}`);
 console.log(`  Created: ${file.timeCreated}`);
 console.log(`  Updated: ${file.updated}`);
// console.log(err);
//console.log(projectId);
//console.log(authClient);
 google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
 if (err) {
   throw err;
 }
console.log(err) 
console.log(projectId);

const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });
    console.log(`gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`);
   dataflow.projects.templates.create({
  projectId: projectId,
  resource: {

 parameters: {
   inputFile: `gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`,
   output_Table: 'titanium-gamma-212906:np_cf_1.cf1',
   //bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory: 'gs://test-bucket-np'
 },
 jobName: 'json-bq1',
 gcsPath: 'gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_BigQuery',
 //jobName: 'json-bq1',
 //gcsPath: 'gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_BigQuery',
 //output_Table: 'titanium-gamma-212906:np_cf_1.cf1',
 //javascriptTextTransformFunctionName: 'transform',
 //bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory: 'gs://test-bucket-np'
 }
 }, function(err, response) {
 if (err) {
 console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
 }
 console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
 callback();
 });

 });

callback();
};`
```

**package.json**

```
"name": "sample-cloud-storage",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "googleapis": "24.0.0"
  }
}
```

**The LOG:**

[image: The LOG]

Thanks in advance folks.

Answer (score 2):

The GCS_Text_to_Bigquery template has several required parameters that seem to be missing in your call:

1. "The GCS location of the text you'd like to process"
   inputFilePattern
2. "JSON file with BigQuery Schema description"
   JSONPath
3. "Output topic to write to"
   outputTable
4. "GCS path to javascript fn for transforming output"
   javascriptTextTransformGcsPath
5. "UDF Javascript Function Name"
   javascriptTextTransformFunctionName
6. "Temporary directory for BigQuery loading process"
   bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory